# Flex image component not canvas container when added to canvas

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am adding a flex image component to a mx:canvas component with a fairly large image. I have the horizontal and vertical scroll policies set to "on", but when I add the image to the canvas, it doesn't expand to show the whole image (the scrollbars aren't activated).

Anybody else have this issue.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
<mx:Canvas  id="myCanvas" minWidth="0" minHeight="0"  horizontalScrollPolicy="on" verticalScrollPolicy="on">



    </mx:Canvas>
```

and the script adding the image

```
var newImg:Image = new Image();
newImg.source = $value.sourceImg;
newImg.x = $value.positionX;
newImg.y = $value.positionY;
newImg.scaleX = $value.scaleX * _scaleRatio ;
newImg.scaleY = $value.scaleY * _scaleRatio;
newImg.rotation = $value.rotation;
myCanvas.addChild(newImg);
```

Comment: Does the image scale to the size you are expecting, but is clipped to the canvas size with no scrollbars?

Comment: yes. That is exactly what it is doing.

Comment: does it help to know that this is in a popup?  I am using the popupmanager to call apopup with the canvas in it. Then adding the large images.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I had to use clipCOntent = true. I had clipContent="false", I thought the meant that it would clip the image and anything outside the bounds could just be scrolled, buut it actually just clips it and doesn't offer a scroll.

Comment: Good to know. I'm with you, I would have expected the opposite behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted your code, but without seeing it I would recommend setting minWidth="0" on the canvas.  This is an old trick to force a re-measure of the canvas so it shows the scroll bars properly.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **canvas.rawChildren.addChild(img)** instead of **canvas.addChild(img)**. That's worked for me before, otherwise you'll need to hook into the Flex component measuring system - but this is very seldomly necessary.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Create a first canvas (viewCanvas) and place another canvas inside it (imageCanvas).

Set the scroll policies on the imageCanvas to 'off'. This should work, and the viewCanvas should have scrollbars. **Note** that no width/height are specified on the imageCanvas or image in code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

    <mx:Canvas id="viewCanvas" x="95" y="65" width="169" height="159">

        <mx:Canvas id="imageCanvas" x="0" y="0" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
            <mx:Image x="0" y="0">
                <mx:source>http://www.beach-holiday.cn/beach-holiday/pics/2009/09/florida-fort-lauderdale.jpg</mx:source>
            </mx:Image>
        </mx:Canvas>

    </mx:Canvas>

</mx:Application>
```